# Do I need to do a BIOS update?

Tags: cpu, bios, updates, intel-core-i7

As I am very interested in computer hardware but do not want to waste some valuable hardware, I decided to upgrade an old PC with an [ECS H61H2-M12](https://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_SPEC/EN/Motherboard/H61H2-M12%20-LL-V1-DO-0-RR-/Socket%201155-LL-Intel-RR-) motherboard. One of the changes I want to make is to upgrade the processor from a Core [i3-2100](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53422/intel-core-i3-2100-processor-3m-cache-3-10-ghz.html) to a Core [i7-2700K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/61275/intel-core-i7-2700k-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html).

Problem: when I install the i7, the computer doesn't start (fans and lights are on, but nothing apears on screen) and it works again when I put back the i3.
Could the solution bo to update the BIOS ?

PS: I already tried an update and it told me something like 'failed because ME_UNLOCK is not shorted' and I don't really know what it means so I prefer to ask the question before breaking anything.

Comment: Typically, the machine would turn on, even if an incompatible CPU is installed.  Are you positive the replacement CPU is functional?  Additionally, are you sure the cpu, is even compatible with your device?  What is the revision (date) of the installed BIOS?

Comment: I bought the CPU on ebay. The seller seemed legit, but there is always the possibility that I got scammed or that it was damaged during transport. What do you mean by "would turn on" ? Sould I see something ? Being able to access the boot menu ?

Comment: Yes; I would expect to see a message indicating an incompatible CPU was installed, please answer my question about the BIOS date.

Comment: No physical incompatibility; both the i3-2100 and the i7-2700K use an 1155 socket, and the motherboard specifies compatibility with Gen2 Intel CPUs. Hpwever, the manual will still be useful http://download.ecs.com.tw/dlfileecs/manual/mb/H61H2-M12/H61H2-M12%20V1.0C%20MANUAL%20low.pdf

Comment: Ramhound, in the BIOS menu I can see two things: the build date, which is 08/05/2011, and the version of the last Intel ME version, 7.0.4.1197, which was published in may 2011 and last updated in november 2011. I hope this is the information you wanted.

Comment: The Intel Management Engine is not the BIOS version we're hoping for. In the top line of my answer below, I've found the link to your manual. Go to its Page 26 and look at the bottom line of the first picture; that's where you find the BIOS version number currently installed.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual for your motherboard](http://download.ecs.com.tw/dlfileecs/manual/mb/H61H2-M12/H61H2-M12%20V1.0C%20MANUAL%20low.pdf) describes that ME_UNLOCK header on pages 10 and 18.  Their FAQ states [it must be unlocked for BIOS update](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Support/Support_FAQ_Detail/EN/General%20FAQ/119), then closed again after the revision in your firmware.

The [BIOS page](https://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_DOWNLOAD/EN/Motherboard/H61H2-M12%20-LL-V1-DO-0-RR-/Socket%201155-LL-Intel-RR-) for that motherboard has its downloads available; however, the i7-2700 K is only an Sandy Bridge (Gen 2) whereas the BIOS on the BIOS page is described as for the Gen3 Ivy Bridge CPUs. Therefore, contacting ECS support is a good idea at this point.